# JS Array is not received by c# webapi

Tags: c#, .net, ajax

I have a test js function that should post data to webapi by Post method

```
function test() {
    var puffs = [];
    var puffObject = {
        id: "2735943",
        priority: "1"
    };

    puffs.push(puffObject);
    puffs.push(puffObject);

    var dto =
    {
        po: puffs
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../api/PuffPriority/",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(dto),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, status) {
            if (data) {
                console.log("Welcome");
            } else {
                console.log("No data");
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

In the controller class i have

```
public void Post(PuffPriority[] po){
//Do something here with po, but po is always empty
}
```

where PuffPriority Model is

```
public class PuffPriority
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string priority { get; set; }
}
```

I dont know whats wrong , the values are sent by JS but api Controller don't fetch it :( Please help, i have already wasted a lot of time.

Comment: What's the actual POST body?

Comment: Is the webservice, or whatever you post to, configured to receive json? That is not the case by default..

Comment: Try with a List in C# method, because you are sending an array of objects because you `push` the array twice in your code. The way I used a object in C# is to specify in ajax = `data: {po: JSON.Stringify(dto)}` that way you are telling to send the po parameter to C#, if that does not work, try with a List<YourViewModel> instead of an array

Comment: Assuming your controller is in /Controllers/PuffPriorityController.cs, change your link to `url: "/api/PuffPriority"` or `url: "@Url.Action("PuffPriority","Api")",` and try changing the definition to `public void Post([FromBody]PuffPriority[] po){`

Comment: Is your controller method actually getting called?

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. It worked with the list. Changed my method to 

[FromBody]List<PuffPriority> po

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed

```
public void Post(PuffPriority[] po){ 
//Do something here with po, but po is always empty 
}
```

To

```
[FromBody]List<PuffPriority> po{
//Do something here with po, but po is always empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in your code.
Simply change

```
url: "../api/PuffPriority/"
```

to

```
url: "../api/Post/"
```

or change your method name from Post to PuffPriority

Comment: In WebAPI it should be "/api/PuffPriority" assuming it's called `PuffPriorityController` and is in the base `Controllers` directory

Comment: Sorry this dint worked. But thanks for the help anyway.